# How do I make my footer a stick to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

Hello I have made a footer for my website and I thought it would work for all my pages but when i try adding it to the second page it leaves a gap at the bottom of the page! 
[image]

on my index page I don't have this problem can someone help!

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h4>Links</h4>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="courses.html">Courses</a></li>
                <li><a href="sign-up.html">Sign Up</a></li>
                <li><a href="log-in.html">Log In</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h4>Social Media</h4>
                <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Youtube</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.footer {
    height: 200px;
    border-top: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
}
.footer li {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
.footer h4 {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

How I did the text at the bottom

```
<div class="more-info">
    <div class="container">
            <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
            <a>|</a>
            <a href="#">Terms</a>
            <ul class="pull-right">
            <a></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.learn-more h3 {
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 23px
}
.learn-more a {
color: #00b0ff;
text-decoration: underline;
font-size: 15px;
}
.learn-more {
height: 480px;
}
```

Comment: It would help if you included the relevant css.

Comment: Sounds like you need a "sticky footer"...try googling that.

Comment: @Paulie_D's suggestion will get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Tried this it just seems to mess it all up haha

Comment: You could refer this for making a stickey footer then http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 0):

I am not pretty sure, is this all, what you wanted. Please check the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/n7vvoazy/).

Please have a look at the code below:

**HTML**

```
<div class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h4>Links</h4>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="courses.html">Courses</a></li>
            <li><a href="sign-up.html">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="log-in.html">Log In</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h4>Social Media</h4>
            <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Youtube</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more-info">    
        <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
        <a>|</a>
        <a href="#">Terms</a>
        <ul class="pull-right">
        <a></a>
        </ul>
     </div>
   </div>            
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.footer {
height: 200px;
border-top: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
}
.footer li {
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
margin-left: 0;
margin-top: 2px;
}
.footer h4 {
font-weight: bold;
margin-top: 30px;
}
.learn-more h3 {
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 23px
}
.learn-more a {
color: #00b0ff;
text-decoration: underline;
font-size: 15px;
}
.learn-more {
height: 480px;
}
```